# Login to the Identity Server Using Another Identity Server - SAML2

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm currently working with **WSO2** suite and I've been trying to do an example from wso2 official documentation server, that you can find [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Login+to+the+Identity+Server+Using+Another+Identity+Server+-+SAML2). I already configure everything step by step and when i run **travelocity** application in my localhost it looks like the example says, i click in the link and it redirects me to **Identity Server** login. I type in user and password, and then it redirects me to **travelocity** home page, but then i run into this error: **SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On**
Error when processing the authentication request!

I check out the debuging log and it says that authentication succeeded and **Identity Server** sent the response to travelocity.

I have no idea what could be happening, please help me out.

I shared the log files [here](https://mega.nz/#F!SYsShZSZ!mikaQwQXwEZ-Oi_EFQOAVw). My English is bad and i'm new working with WSO2, please be patient with me.

Comment: can you share the configurations of the two identity server SPs and travelocity.com?

In particular, can you check whether the travelocity.properties options,

SAML2.EnableResponseSigning /
SAML2.EnableAssertionSigning /
SAML2.EnableAssertionEncryption /
SAML2.EnableRequestSigning

match that of the first IS (IS that has travelocity registered as an SP), my

Comment: Can you attach wso2carbon.log and tomcat catalina.log files?

Answer (score 0):

The logs at WSO2 IS side says `Signature validation for Authentication Request failed`. The possible reason could be that you have not selected the correct certificate alias at WSO2 IS.

To do that, edit your service provider's SAML configuration and update the `Certificate Alias` with the correct value. In default case it should have the value `wso2carbon`. In case you have configured it to something else, select the one you have configured.